# Can run() return objects?

Tags: java, runnable, timertask

Assuming that this is the scenario:

```
class A extends TimerTask{
  int a;
  public void run(){
    //operation to be performed periodically
  }
}
```

and

```
class B{
  int delay=2000,interval=3000;
  A objectA;
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Timer t=new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new A(),delay,interval);
  }
}
```

Can't `run()` return objects? If I make such a change, incompatibility is cited. Why?

Comment: Who would that object be returned to?

Comment: The reason incompatibility is cited is the abstract class `TimerTask` defines run to be `void`.  I suppose you could pass a `Runnable` to `A` at construction to get called back on completion of `run()`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the method-declaration, the returntype of run is void. Therefore the method can't directly return an object. But what you can do, is storing an object at the instance-level of class `A` and declaring a method on `A` from which you can get the stored object, when it's operation is finished

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`FutureTask`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) (and [`Future`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)) with [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (see examples on API pages).

---

### Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

     FutureTask<String> future = 
             new FutureTask<String>(new Callable<String>() {
         public String call() {
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return "Hello World!";
         }
     });

     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
     executor.execute(future);

     System.out.println(future.get());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is having void return type.
But you can make it to return somthing like this

The easiest way is probably to store it in a known location. For example, you can put it in some hashtable, with the thread name as the key. And this hashtable location could be set in the constructor of the runnable object.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you make it return something other than `void`, you're not respecting the contract of the method you override, which is declared in [`TimerTask`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#run%28%29) as

```
public abstract void run();
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `run()` is `void`, so the short answer is no, you can't return objects.

If you want to retrieve results from code that executes periodically, you might find [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) a useful alternative to Timer. Its `schedule` methods return a `ScheduledFuture` which you can retrieve the results from.